# Create very large edge and vertex graphs in C#

Tags: c#, graph, quickgraph

I am attempting to map out social networks

For example, i have person A and he has 5 followers, these followers and the person would be represented by a vertex, and then have an edge connecting them. And most likely, at least half of them are following each other, creating a big sort of "web".

I tried doing this in QuickGraph, however i ran into a few issues:

1. The graph ends up looking like more like a flow chart then a web, example from earlier in QuickGraph:

[image]

2. When i test with real data, the graph just becomes a huge, laggy, spaghetti mess of ink

What would be the best way to create this sort of graph?

For reference i am looking to make a graph that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem you are asking about is... the first and second graphs can't easily be compared subjectively / visually. Also it sounds like QG runs slowly... by what measure? Do you have some data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the data structure you are working with is a Directed Graph - that is, the edges of your node have a direction, from follower to followed.

It looks like you are using [dot](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/dotguide.pdf) to render your graph, which is a great way to lay things out if your data has some kind of start and end - if there is an overall sense of earlier to later, sources to sinks, simpler to more complex.

You don't really have that, and your example picture is more typical of an *undirected* graph. The same people that do `dot` also do [neato](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/neatoguide.pdf), which gives you diagrams much closer to your desired picture.

I don't know QuickGraph's API at all, but I'd look to either;

- change the graph data structure you're creating -- try switching to something like [`UndirectedGraph`](http://yaccconstructor.github.io/QuickGraph/reference/quickgraph-undirectedgraph-2.html) and see if that ends up switching the render
- see if there are options in your render method to render an undirected graph rather than a directed graph.